# Why does my Cosmos DB collection decrease in size over time?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

So I'm parsing data into a Cosmos Collection and my parse finished at 2:45.
No other transactions have taken place, what is Cosmos doing that my collection size decreases?

[image]